# html input working incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML Forumlar which is processed with ajax. This means it loads the page again not to the process Forumlar. My problem is that when he submits the form by pressing enter the pointer loaded in the input field, which I do not want to. does anyone know how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){    
    $("#myForm input").keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I assume you have jQuery imported because you have tagged your question with jQuery, and I also assume that you are importing jQuery **before** you are trying to run this code? If so, are you placing this inside a `$(document).ready(function(){//Here});` or inside a `$(function(){//Here});`?

Comment: well , try this code   $("#myForm input").off(" $("keypress");
   $("#myForm input").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // perform custom staff 
            }
    });